# This keyword referring to a parent variable

Tags: java, inheritance, this

Today a fellow learner came up with an interesting query. We know that `this` keyword is used to refer to the current object. But I could not explain to him how `this` keyword behaves as seen in the following snippet. I know what inheritance is: allows access to parent class variables and methods. **But are they copied into the memory area of child instance?, because I am able to use this keyword to access the parent class property.**

I was able to refer to parent class variable. I searched and found that nothing gets copied *virtually* to child class, but why the following behavior happens? Please explain this case of using `this`.

```
class Parent {
   int a=10;
}

public class Child extends Parent{

  void m1(){
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(this.a);
    System.out.println(super.a);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    new Child().m1();
  }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: it's because it is inherited. Child has an IS-A relationship with Parent.

Comment: this doesn't refer to the current class but to the current instance of an object. This instance has all the attributes and methods form its class. Including those inherited from superclasses or interfaces.

Comment: Yes, but it does not clears me about how using this I am able to access Parent class property when compared to using super to do the same thing. Hope I am getting it clear.
Can you clear a query: Is the code copied to my child class instance ? (Internally)

Answer (score 3):

The property `a` is inherited by `Child`. Therefore, you can use `this.a` in child to reference it.

**Where was the problem supposed to be?**

> I searched and found that nothing gets copied virtually to child class

You have the wrong example to illustrate that statement.

The way to understand that is (roughly): "instance variables are not overridden when re-declared in subclasses, so you can't declare an instance as `Parent` and expect to get `Child.a` if the instance was created with `new Child()`". Here's an example of the problematic case:

```
class Parent {
   int a = 10;
}

public class Child extends Parent{

  int a = 12; //not overridden

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Parent child = new Child();
    System.out.println(child.a); //This will print 10, not 12
  }
}
```

`System.out.println(child.a);` will print `10` because variables instance fields don't get overridden. You get the value based on the declared type (`Parent` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a class Child it contains all members of itself and of Parent. However, private members of Parent are not accessible from Child:

```
class Parent {
   private int p = 10;
}

public class Child extends Parent{

  void m1(){
    System.out.println(p); // compilation error
  }

}
```

Another interesting case is when one instance of Parent tries to access a private field of another instance of Parent. What do you think happens?

```
public class Parent {
    private int p = 11;

    public boolean same(Parent other) {
        return other.p == p;
    }
}
```

You might think `other.p` will result in a compilation error since `p` is a private field. However, since privacy does not pertain to object instances, but to classes. So all private fields in Parent are visible within all Parent instances, so this works!

Answer (score 0):

Consider below Code:

- this is a reference variable which will point to the current object.
- super is used to refer to Parent's property in case you have created
  the same in the child.

  ```
  class Product{

      String color;

      public Product() {
          color = "Black";
      }
  }

  class Mobile extends Product{

      String color;

      Mobile(){
          color = "White";
      }

      void showMobileData(){

          System.out.println("this hashCode is "+this.hashCode());
          System.out.println("super hashCode is: "+super.hashCode());

          System.out.println("color is: "+color);
          System.out.println("this.color is: "+this.color);
          System.out.println("super.color is: "+super.color);
      }
  }

  public class Test {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          //new Mobile().showMobileData();
          Mobile mRef = new Mobile();
          System.out.println("mRef HashCode: "+mRef.hashCode());

          mRef.showMobileData();
      }

  }
  ```